# PostgreSQL - return string when testing integer with case statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, conditional-statements, case

When selecting some data from a table I'd like to use a `CASE` statement to return "n/a" in the event of a null value.

This is a simplified but representative version of the table I'm looking at:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    paid_cents INTEGER NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

INSERT INTO test VALUES (1, 100);
INSERT INTO test VALUES (2, NULL);
INSERT INTO test VALUES (3, 0);
```

I'd expect to be able to use the following query:

```sql
SELECT CASE
    WHEN paid_cents IS NULL THEN 'n/a'
    ELSE paid_cents / 100
    END AS "dollar amount"
FROM test
```

[A fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/38c7f5/1/0) of this behaves exactly as I'd expect. However trying this on my real database (PostgreSQL 9.4) results in an error:

> ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: "n/a"
>   LINE 2: WHEN paid_cents IS NULL THEN 'n/a'

It seems that Postgres is expecting an integer to be returned when testing an integer (and changing 'n/a' to a number does indeed work). I'm guessing that I'll need to `CAST` somewhere?

Comment: postgres treats NULL as unknown - maybe `WHEN paid_cents IS NULL THEN NULL` will serve?.. because you can't mix datatyopes in column - it is ether int or char

Answer (score 7, accepted):

either use `NULL`:

```
SELECT CASE
    WHEN paid_cents IS NULL THEN NULL
    ELSE paid_cents / 100
    END AS "dollar amount"
FROM test
```

or cast both to string:

```
SELECT CASE
    WHEN paid_cents IS NULL THEN 'n/a'
    ELSE (paid_cents / 100)::text
    END AS "dollar amount"
FROM test
```

Comment: Casting both to string is what I needed. Thanks very much.

Comment: sure, glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot mix datatypes in the columns. As previous answer suggest you should go to a textual datatype (char/varchar/text etc...)

I would use ANSI-SQL and cast( expression as datatype) instead of :: datatype. Same functionality but would be portable between most database engines.

In this case it would be 
cast( (paid_cents/100)  as text) 
instead of 
(paid_cents/100) :: text

Cheers.